# Jenkins: Enhancing a plugin for Jenkins -- how does the plugin code access the Job's "parameterized build" string?

Tags: plugins, build, jenkins, hudson, parameter-passing

I am looking for any good doc Jenkins how-to make a plugin - the more thorough the better.

**Importantly** : from within the plugin Java code how does one reference the "parameterized build" string?

Answer (score 1):

There is the official tutorial https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial.

You can download any plugin from its github page and build it.

This plugin uses parameters in a different way to apply a patch to the workspace

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Patch+Parameter+Plugin

Which could help